# Paraphase of "the power to conjure reality through writing"

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition, literature

> It was like an enactment of the world inhabited by the protagonist of Moshfegh’s forthcoming novel, “My Year of Rest and Relaxation,” who works at a gallery in Chelsea, amid objects like a quarter-million-dollar “pair of toy monkeys made using human pubic hair,” with camera penises poking out from their fur. “Did I do this?” Moshfegh said, only half kidding. **She sometimes gets the sense that she has the power to conjure reality through her writing.**
>
> <sub>*The New Yorker*, [Ottessa Moshfegh’s Otherworldly Fiction](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/07/09/ottessa-moshfeghs-otherworldly-fiction) By Ariel Levy</sub>

Is the bolded part trying to say she felt she was a magician can turn reality into fiction? I don’t think it makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question regarding meaning of “spell out”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/question-regarding-meaning-of-spell-out)

Comment: Have you looked up the verb **conjure** in *several* dictionaries to get a good sense of its range of meaning?  Because there are so many good dictionaries online these days, this site discourages questions about basic meaning.  You should indicate what you think the sentence might mean, having consulted some dictionaries, and then say why it still makes no sense to you.

Comment: Do you understand what "sometimes gets the sense"  means?

Comment: Closely related: [“Conjure” vs “conjure up”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70437/conjure-vs-conjure-up)

Answer (score 1):

From [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-a-sense-that-get-a-sense-that)

> **have a sense that/get a sense that**
>   If you *have a sense* that something is true or *get a sense* that something is true, you think that it is true.
>
> [mainly spoken]
>   *Do you have the sense that you are loved by the public?*
>   *I get a sense that people are feeling better about themselves.*

Thus "she sometimes gets the sense" means she has a general *sensation* or understanding that books are somewhat magical. Similar to a magician, the author *[conjures](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conjure)* (creates/produces) reality through the power of words (as if by magic). In fact, when the author asks “Did I do this?” she is referring to the New York art fair with its surreal and gaudy works of art on display.